# restrict user from changing input field's date unless when using datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am building a web application that uses the jquery datepicker to get dates to make a booking.
Although the datepicker works well, I have had issues when a user sets the checkin/checkout dates manually in the inputfield since I cannot validate the date using dataepicker's onSelect when such an event occurs. This has left loopholes where the checkindate can be higher than the checkoutdate. 
here is my html code for an checkin

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="checkoutdate" name="checkoutdate" placeholder=""/>
```

And here is my jquery for selecting a daterange

```
function checkincheckoutdates(checkin,checkout,feedback)
{
    $('#'+checkout).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#'+checkin).datepicker(
    {
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate:0,
        onSelect: function(dateText,inst)
        {
            var startdate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
            var nextday = new Date(startdate.getTime()+86400000);
            $("#"+checkout).datepicker("option","minDate",nextday);
            if($("#"+checkout).val().trim() == ''){
                $("#"+checkout).val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy',nextday));//.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    });
     $("#"+checkout).datepicker(
     {
        onSelect: function(dateText,inst)
        {
            var startdate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
            var prevday = new Date(startdate.getTime()-86400000);
            $("#"+checkin).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",prevday);

    });
```

So question is, How do i restrict the user from entering the date with the datepicker only

Answer (score 2):

you can use `keyup()` event to restrict user to enter date manually on date inputs like this:

```
$("input[type='date']").on('keyup',function(){
alert("select date using datepicker");
$(this).val("");
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bRE67/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `readonly` attribute to your checkin & checkout `textboxes`. This will prevent the users from entering any unwanted values and also disallow the manual editing of the dates when again focusing in into the datepicker textboxes after selecting the dates from the datpickers. Do like this:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="checkoutdate" name="checkoutdate" placeholder="" readonly/>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="checkindate" name="checkoutdate" placeholder="" readonly/>
```